# Unpacking s3.ObjectSummary from bucket.objects.all() iteration

Tags: python, tuples, boto, iterable-unpacking

I'm using boto3 to download files from s3, and i'm trying to unpack the values from bucket.objects.all() iteration:

```
bucket = boto3.Session(profile_name='default').resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name)
for (bucket_name, key) in zip(bucket.objects.all()):
   print(bucket_name, key)
```

But this is returning the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

What I'm doing wrongly?

Comment: check the value of `zip(bucket.objects.all())` exactly, if you don't have a list of tuples with two members, you can't use this syntax in a for loop

Comment: The value is: (s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='some-bucket', key='RE.xlsx'),)

Comment: so you have only 1 object, you need to extract the attributes of the this object before unpacking to match with `bucket_name` and `key`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this part instead of `zip(bucket.objects.all())`:

```
map(lambda x: (x.bucket_name, x.key), bucket.objects.all())
```

the function `map` allows to apply the function lambda (first parameter) to each members of the second parameter 
`bucket.objects.all()` which returns a list of ObjectSummary.

`map` returns a list you can loop

The lambda returns a tuple of 2 values so that you can unpack them.

Comment: This should be the right answer. 

Basically the `ObjectSummary` returns as the name say, the entire S3 object related with a particular key. Using the lambda as described you can extract some particular pieces/metadata of this object.